# Enable remote access for Postgres DB 9.6 on MacOS Sierra

Tags: postgresql, macos-sierra

I'm struggling to enable remote access for Postgres DB version 9.6 on MacOS Sierra.

What I have done so far:

- modify postgres.conf, set listen_addresses = "*"
- modify pg_hb.conf, add these lines:

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5

host    all             all             *                       md5

- I checked the Firewall setting (GUI), and see the postgres process is allowing incoming connections.

From PgAdmin tool running on the macOS machine, I can use the ip of macOS machine to connect to the PG database.

The result of running netstat -an | grep 5432:

tcp4       0      0  *.5432                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  *.5432                 *.*                    LISTEN
d06ae6d89823b48f stream      0      0 d06ae6d89b32fcb7                0                0                0 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

However, I couldn't access to the PG database from another machine in same wifi network. (I can ping the ip of the PG database machine).

Any idea of suggestion is highly appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: The result of running netstat -an | grep 5432:

tcp4       0      0  *.5432                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.5432                 *.*                    LISTEN     
d06ae6d89823b48f stream      0      0 d06ae6d89b32fcb7                0                0                0 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

Comment: You should add that information to the question, not in a comment

Comment: I modified the question, thank @fvu.

Comment: can you telnet to port 5432? Are you certain that you're not ALREADY running another postgres on that port already? Apple comes with postgres loaded and listening on 5432 by default. To run an additional PG instance, just put it on another port like 6432

Comment: Seems like I couldn't telnet to port 5432, nor port 6432.